# Switching across region for failover

Tags: google-app-engine

We are trying to build a fault tolerant architecture. The objective is to switchover to solution on another zone in case of failure. The following is the situation

1. Our solution is build over Google AppEngine using Java. We use datastore as db.
2. Currently it is deployed on a X zone of AppEngine.
3. We have now replicated the same environment on a different region.
4. When a failover occurrs we would like to forward the request to the replicated zone.

How to achieve it? It seems their is options for Compute Engine but our solution is using AppEngine where instance are managed by the Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom domain you can deploy your failover to `www2.example.com` and just forward the request with a DNS server if your main app is completely down, or let the main app redirect to the failover if the main app itself finds it is failing.

Comment: I have a custom domain(*.example.com, where * represents each customer). My dns entry points to ghs.googlehosted.com.